# How registering the output of a SourceSets for the dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with the java plugin applied, and an additionnal source set

```
project(':dependencie') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceSets {
        generated {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/generated/java'
            }
        }
        main {
            compileClasspath += generated.output
            runtimeClasspath += generated.output
        }
        test {
            compileClasspath += generated.output
            runtimeClasspath += generated.output
        }
    }
}
```

And another depending of this one :

```
project(':dependsFrom') {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile(
                project(':dependencie')
        ) { transitive = false }
    }
}
```

My problemes is that when I am trying to compile dependsFrom, it doesn't find the classes of the sourceSet `generated` for the project `dependencie`. My workaround is to add the line

```
output.dir(generated.output, builtBy: 'regenerateFromWsdl')
```

to the `main` source set of `dependencie` but any insight to how "registering" the  output of the `generated` source set for future dependencies would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to model the generated code as a separate source set, you have to create a Jar and publish it via the `runtime` configuration:

```
task generatedJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.generated.output
}

artifacts {
    runtime generatedJar
}
```

Alternatively, you could add `src/generated/java` as another source directory for the `main` source set, in which case it will get compiled/packaged/exported together with that.

Comment: I want to keep one jar by project, so your first solution does not work. Additionnaly, your second solution is only a variation of my workaround (integrating generated sourceSet into the main sourceSet0

Comment: It's not a workaround, but a common solution (without the extra source set). The drawback of putting multiple source set outputs into the same Jar is that it means having different granularities for compile/test and package, which is something I'd generally try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I found a solution. You just need to add the generated sourceSet output to the jar task of dependencie project, as it is this same jar task which "inject" the project into the dependecie system.

My problem was that I tought that any additional sourceSet of the project would have been automatically used by all the tasks of the project.

Here the modified gradle script

```
project(':dependencie') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceSets {
        generated {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/generated/java'
            }
        }
        main {
            compileClasspath += generated.output
            runtimeClasspath += generated.output
        }
        test {
            compileClasspath += generated.output
            runtimeClasspath += generated.output
        }
    }
    jar {
        from sourceSets.generated.output
    }
}
```